# Updated code for my post about mysql with foreach echo

Tags: mysql, css, foreach, echo

```
$categories = array();
$result= mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM products ORDER BY category, nr ");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

        $categories[$row['category']][] = $row['design'];
        $categories[$row['category']][] = $row['img'];
    $categories[$row['category']][] = $row['name'];
$categories[$row['category']][] = $row['descr'];
$categories[$row['category']][] = $row['preprice'];
    $categories[$row['category']][] = $row['price'];
$categories[$row['category']][] = $row['unit'];
}


foreach($categories as $key => $category){
    echo $key.'<br/>';//prints categories 
    foreach($category as $item){ 
    //echo $item.'<br/>';//prints rows within categories
    echo '<div class="'.$category[0].'">
  <img src="'.$category[1].'" width="100%"><br>
  <span><b>'.$category[2].'</b></span><br><span>'.$category[3].'</span><br />
    <span>'.$category[4].'&nbsp;</span><span>'.$category[5].'</span><span>&nbsp;'.$category[6].'</span></div>
';


    }
}
```

It displays like this http://gartenundhof.de/gartenundhof-produkte5.php
It should look like this:http://gartenundhof.de/gartenundhof-produkte.php

Comment: Please turn your post into a QUESTION. No-one is interested that you made a mistake, just put here your question as it is. Try to imagine yourself as a future reader of your own post, brought to StackOverflow by google - what benefit would you have from SUCH A POST like yours now?

Comment: My question is: Why does the echo show only the first product of each category, In the first category are 3 products, but it echoes the first product 21 times.

Comment: Completely reword your post! Do not ask in comment, change the title, "Updated code for my post about mysql with foreach echo" is not what you want to ask. Remove your comment.
Again: imagine yourself searching internet for an answer and google will bring you to a post with title "Updated code for my post about mysql with foreach echo". Would it find it helpful? Think about stackoverflow as about a KNOWLEDGE BASE, not a CHAT SERVER. And btw, fix the formatting of your code, it's ugly now :)
Remove the external links, replace them with screenshot which you include into your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot Honza for your kind remarks. I will try to be a good boy in the future.

Comment: velorider, be a good boy now, not only in the future! :)